# Using a memory mapped file as a swap file?

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I'm working in Android where memory is limited and there is no swap file like feature. I've read that people have implemented swap file like functionality using memory mapped files in their apps but I don't understand how this would work. Does anyone know?

I think the general idea is that, if my program wanted to use an int array that was the size of say 20Mb, I could create the data for this array in a 20Mb file and then use the memory mapped file feature to transparently bring into memory the parts of the file I current need to read and write to. The crucial element is that, although I have 20Mb of space to read/write to, only a small fraction of this is ever in memory at a time (Android apps are limited to ~24Mb of memory).

I'd prefer to work in Java for this but a C solution would also work.

Edit: This memory mapped file trick is mentioned here but I don't understand how it would work http://grammerjack.blogspot.com/2009/10/gles-quake-port-of-quake-to-android.html

Comment: Isn't swap a file-mapped memory?

Comment: Android has no swap configured.  Because of the way apps work, the OS is allowed to kill anything that isn't in the foreground when memory gets low.  Memory-mapped files work best for read-only data (pages can be discarded individually), though you could also do shared read/write to get swap-like behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, use java.nio.MappedByteBuffer.

In C, use the POSIX function mmap(). It works on Android fine.

Comment: Note that for the dirty pages in the mapping to remain file-backed, you must supply the `MAP_SHARED` flag to `mmap()`.

Comment: As Java has a feature called "memory mapped files", I'm confused at the difference between this and mmap. Either way, how do I restrict how much of the file is in memory at a time? I need to be conscience how much memory is being used and mmap just seems to ask for the size of file to map. What would happen to memory if I allocated all of the 20Mb file?

Comment: If you're talking about class android.os.MemoryFile, then it's not it - it's shared memory. If you try to allocate more memory by mapping that the system has, mmap will error out. Whether to map the whole file or not is up to you. mmap does not ask for the *file* size - it asks for the size of the mapping, thus giving you the option of mapping just a part of the whole file.

Comment: Here's what I mean about Java memory mapped files; they sound exactly the same as mmap: http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ314_029.htm I'm really confused about mmap now. I thought the point was, it managed bringing the parts of your large file into and out of memory on demand as indicated in the first paragraph from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap.

Comment: You're right; I take that back. There are memory-mapped files on Android Java after all.